# Why does my SlowCheetah configuration not work?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, slowcheetah

I'm developing a WPF application on VS 2017 Community.

I've download SlowCheetah, so this is my

**App.Debug.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="application.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

**App.Release.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Now, whatever I choose "Debug" or "Release", nothing changes to app.config.
Furthermore, clicking preview Transform to both files always show me app.config original content.
Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enable transforms on the config file. Right click on your project, Select **Unload project**. Right click again select **Edit xxx.csproj**.

Scroll to the bottom of the XML file.

It should look something like:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.48\build\SlowCheetah.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.48\build\SlowCheetah.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\BuildWebCompiler.1.11.359\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\BuildWebCompiler.1.11.359\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  <Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.48\build\SlowCheetah.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.48\build\SlowCheetah.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\BuildWebCompiler.1.11.359\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\BuildWebCompiler.1.11.359\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets')" />
```

Insert the following XML:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="App.config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" Destination="App.config" />
  </Target>
```

so it now looks like

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.48\build\SlowCheetah.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.48\build\SlowCheetah.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\BuildWebCompiler.1.11.359\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\BuildWebCompiler.1.11.359\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="App.config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" Destination="App.config" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  <Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.48\build\SlowCheetah.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.48\build\SlowCheetah.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\BuildWebCompiler.1.11.359\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\BuildWebCompiler.1.11.359\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets')" />
```

right click select **reload project**. Rebuild.

also ensure your config files are nested correctly, they should look like this:

```
   <Content Include="App.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="App.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="App.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
```